# Android VideoView crop_center

Tags: android, android-videoview, aspect-ratio

I have a `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoViewPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And what I need is to show video fullscreen cropped. If I could compare to ImageView, I need to show it as crop_center.

How can I make VideoView not to auto-resize video to fit center, but crop center?

Comment: This solution for a VideoView scales Center Crop or Center Inside keeping the aspect ratio of the video like an ImageView does. Hope it helps someone! https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641686/6082973

Comment: @Carlitos it won't center crop the video, as it changes the VideoVIew size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to use `TextureView` instead of `VideoView`(`SurfaceView`).
`TextureView`  does not make any manipulations with the content to fit it ti the screen.
Here is the code sample for the solution:

```
//store the SurfaceTexture to set surface for MediaPlayer
mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new SurfaceTextureListener() {
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface,
            int width, int height) {
        FullScreenActivity.this.mSurface = surface;

    }
```

....

```
Surface s = new Surface(mSurface);
mPlayer = mp;
mp.setSurface(s);

scaleVideo(mp);//<-- this function scales video to run cropped
```

....

```
private void scaleVideo(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {

        LayoutParams videoParams = (LayoutParams) mTextureView
                .getLayoutParams();
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        FullScreenActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(dm);

        final int height = dm.heightPixels;
        final int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int videoHeight = mPlayer.getVideoHeight();
        int videoWidth = mPlayer.getVideoWidth();
        double hRatio = 1;

        hRatio = (height * 1.0 / videoHeight) / (width * 1.0 / videoWidth);
        videoParams.x = (int) (hRatio <= 1 ? 0 : Math.round((-(hRatio - 1) / 2)
                * width));
        videoParams.y = (int) (hRatio >= 1 ? 0 : Math
                .round((((-1 / hRatio) + 1) / 2) * height));
        videoParams.width = width - videoParams.x - videoParams.x;
        videoParams.height = height - videoParams.y - videoParams.y;
        Log.e(TAG, "x:" + videoParams.x + " y:" + videoParams.y);
        mTextureView.setScaleX(1.00001f);//<-- this line enables smoothing of the picture in TextureView.
        mTextureView.requestLayout();
        mTextureView.invalidate();

    }
```

Comment: Here's a library that Uses a textureView and has centerCrop added: 

https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-video-crop

Answer (score 31):

In Android's VideoView, here is a simple and easy way to achieve the same effect as `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In JAVA:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         float videoRatio = mp.getVideoWidth() / (float) mp.getVideoHeight();
         float screenRatio = videoView.getWidth() / (float) 
         videoView.getHeight();
         float scaleX = videoRatio / screenRatio;
         if (scaleX >= 1f) {
             videoView.setScaleX(scaleX);
         } else {
             videoView.setScaleY(1f / scaleX);
         }
      }
});
```

In Kotlin:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
    val videoRatio = mediaPlayer.videoWidth / mediaPlayer.videoHeight.toFloat()
    val screenRatio = videoView.width / videoView.height.toFloat()
    val scaleX = videoRatio / screenRatio
    if (scaleX >= 1f) {
        videoView.scaleX = scaleX
    } else {
        videoView.scaleY = 1f / scaleX
    }
}
```

And this worked for me. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. I just had to remove the attribute "android:visibility="gone"

Comment: this too is the only solution that worked for me, i used kotlin one

Comment: not work, i don't know why

Comment: very amaaazing solution , great thnaks :)

Comment: Worked for me in 2023!

Comment: problem after pause if it is inside Viewpager2

Answer (score 2):

To crop center in fullscreen you can still use a VideoView. Set the VideoView width and height to match the parent inside a RelativeLayout and adjust it to be bigger than the screen and set his position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
tools:context="com.example.Activity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in onCreate:

```
   RelativeLayout rootView=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size=new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams rootViewParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.getLayoutParams();
    int videoWidth=864;
    int videoHeight=1280;

    if ((float)videoWidth/(float)videoHeight<(float)size.x/(float)size.y) {
        rootViewParams.width=size.x;
        rootViewParams.height=videoHeight*size.x/videoWidth;
        rootView.setX(0);
        rootView.setY((rootViewParams.height-size.y)/2*-1);
    } else {
        rootViewParams.width=videoWidth*size.y/videoHeight;
        rootViewParams.height=size.y;
        rootView.setX((rootViewParams.width-size.x)/2*-1);
        rootView.setY(0);
    }
    rootView.setLayoutParams(rootViewParams);


    final VideoView mVideoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried similar solution, as it themed obvious to me when asked a question 4 years ago, and that time VideoView was force fitting video inside itself, which prohibited cropping. Don't know how it works now, since 4 years passed, and something has to be changed in the SDK.

Comment: Ok, I imagined that, but I spent some time looking for the solution and this question is clear and shows up in the first positions of google, so I decided to answer. This works for me in api level 25.

Comment: are you sure that it is supposed to **crop**, not to **fit center**?

Comment: You are totally right, it was stretching. I changed the video and it cheated on me. I've just edited the answer with a correct solution using VideoView in a RelativeLayout and adjusting the size and position to be outside the screen. This finally works. Can't believe how such a simple task could be so difficult.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for providing this answer. I am trying to make a login screen like the one Spotify has , but using this solution I am not able to position other elements on the screen well, because the rootview does no longer match the screen. 
Are there any way to do this on *not* the root view? and rather just resize a child of the root view? I tried to do this, but with no luck.

Comment: I don't think so. It has to be the root view, because the childs can't overflow their parent, only the rootview can do that. Maybe you can then set a child view inside the rootview matching the screen size and position everything there.

Comment: No upvotes after all this time? It works perfectly!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I just put video inside `ConstraintLayout` with such parameters. This helped stretch video and achieve `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` effect.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: The default behavior is just like `fitCenter` , so I compute the video ratio(width/height) and screen ratio, and then scale the `VideoView` to full screen. The result is just like `centerCrop` .

Answer (score 0):

Adding an addition to answer by @Nabin. If you are experiencing problem on pause. **If video pause causes the video view height to change and show a black screen below**. use this.

```
public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {
private int originalWidth = 0;
private int originalHeight = 0;

public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (originalWidth == 0 || originalHeight == 0) {
        originalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        originalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(originalWidth, originalHeight);
}
```

}