# How resize TextureView to fullscreen when rotation 90?

Tags: android

I using a `TextureView` to play video:
I have to use `rotation=90` to display video correct orientation when record video

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#777777" >
<TextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

i try set setTransform of TextureView to resize video to fullsreen, but it not working:

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        try {           
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();          
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(FILE_NAME);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();            
            updateTextureViewScaling(width,height);
            // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();                  
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

 private void updateTextureViewScaling(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        float scaleX = 1.0f;
        float scaleY = 1.0f;
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int VIDEO_HEIGHT = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int VIDEO_WIDTH = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        if (VIDEO_WIDTH > viewWidth && VIDEO_WIDTH > viewHeight) {
            scaleX = (float) VIDEO_WIDTH / viewWidth;
            scaleY = (float) VIDEO_HEIGHT / viewHeight;
        } else if (VIDEO_WIDTH < viewWidth && VIDEO_HEIGHT < viewHeight) {
            scaleY = (float) viewWidth / VIDEO_WIDTH;
            scaleX = (float) viewHeight / VIDEO_HEIGHT;
        } else if (viewWidth > VIDEO_WIDTH) {
            scaleY = ((float) viewWidth / VIDEO_WIDTH) / ((float) viewHeight / VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        } else if (viewHeight > VIDEO_HEIGHT) {
            scaleX = ((float) viewHeight / VIDEO_WIDTH) / ((float) viewWidth / VIDEO_WIDTH);
        }

        // Calculate pivot points, in our case crop from center
        int pivotPointX = viewWidth / 2;
        int pivotPointY = viewHeight / 2;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);

        textureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
```

Target result:

Image 1: not set  android:rotation="90"

[image]

Image 2: set  android:rotation="90"

[image]

How can set width and height of video to fullscreen:
i had log:
Width and Height in onSurfaceTextureAvailable = size of Screen.

Comment: i changed updateTextureViewScaling to your setupMatrix, video can't display.

Comment: Must use android:rotation="90"?

Comment: i used setupMatrix(width,height,90);, but it not woking .

Comment: add   android:screenOrientation="sensor"

Comment: where does it add?

Comment: add to tag your activity in manifaest

Comment: Check for solution here when mTextureview rotation 90 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem had fixed by: 
put TextureView in a FrameLayout
and update function updateTextureViewScaling

```
private void updateTextureViewScaling(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) textureView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = viewHeight;
            params.height =viewWidth;
            params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
            textureView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overide this method in Activity:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { 
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       textview.setRotation(90);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
       Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      textview.setRotation(0);
    }
  }
```

in Android Manifest file mention this under activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".
```

Comment: it not ok. i not want rotation screen  when change phone. android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: My problem: if i not set android:rotation="90", video display rotation 90 (image 1). if i set android:rotation="90", size of video display the image 2. i want image 2 , it can fullscreen the same image 1.

Comment: Must i set android:rotation="90" in Layout?

Comment: your code only rotation textview , not set full screen video after rotation.

Comment: Now, i had rotation ok by: android:rotation="90", My problem is full screen for video(Height of video =Height of Screen).

Comment: Do you want to media player full screen in the portrait mode?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/19448550/5027107 You have to crop-center it

Comment: Can't set fullscreen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179665/discussion-between-sajad-zohrei-and-d-t).