# Rotating video messes up MediaControls, android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, redraw, mediacontroller

When I rotate my device, the video controls dont resize properly. I made a video of what I am talking about here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgRythmUo3A

Is there a way to "redraw" the controls?

I made this change to my manifest so I could control what happens when it rotates:

```
<activity android:name="Vforum" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
```

Then my java, I override the `onConfigurationChanged()` method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // redraw controls
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: How do you create MediaController? Dynamically? Do you call setAnchorView and setMediaController to connect it with VideoView?

Answer (score 1):

We need more Info from you here, Mike and/or Ronnie.
First of all, answering mice's questions would be helpful for helpers to help :)

Maybe you should also post the layout - xml. Perhaps there is only a setting you shouldn't have made in the first place.

A little search brought this up:
[Android VideoView orientation change with buffered video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video)

Maybe that one will give you some hints.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the player position and recreate the player with the saved position. That's what I've done in a couple of projects and it seems to work.

Fildor's link should help you with that.