# Resize video to fit the VideoView

Tags: android, android-video-player

I'm positioning a VideoView with AbsoluteLayout (I need to display it on several places into the screen at specific positions).

```
public void showVideo(RectF bounds, final String videoUrl) {
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) video.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) bounds.width();
    params.height = (int) bounds.height();
    params.x = (int) bounds.left;
    params.y = (int) bounds.top;

    video.requestLayout();

    video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    video.setFocusable(true);
    video.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    video.requestFocus();

    File file = new File(videoUrl);
    video.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    video.start();
}
```

But the Video ins't getting resized to the bounds I specified.

Any tips?

Another related question is, how to make the MediaController show over the VideoView?

Comment: You need to resize the video not the view. Try to find some video editor library for that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this is very close to what you are trying. if you are willing to subclass the videoview and `override onMeasure` here is the solution. you need to

```
MyVideoView extends VideoView
```

[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video/4452597#4452597**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video/4452597#4452597)

---

as for showing **MediaController over VidowView**

Declare

```
private MediaController controller = null;
```

OnCreate

```
controller = new MediaController(this);
controller.setMediaPlayer(mcEvents);
controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.wrapper));
```

Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    controller.show();
    return false;
}
```

Media Controller events

```
private MediaController.MediaPlayerControl mcEvents = new MediaController.MediaPlayerControl() {        
    public void start() {
        player.start();
    }

    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        player.seekTo(pos);         
    }

    public void pause() {
        player.pause();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {            
        return player.isPlaying();
    }

    public int getDuration() {          
        return player.getDuration();
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition() {           
        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getBufferPercentage() {          
        return pBuffer;
    }

    public boolean canSeekForward() {           
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

a sample layout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.my.views.MyViedoView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: My biggest problem is not to resize the VideoView, is to resize the Video that was playing inside of it. I want to it assume all the space I specified to the VideoView.

Comment: does not resizing the videoview resize the video aswell? the link i have shown you does change the size of the video in the overriden onMeasure. What i'm missing.

Comment: Well, this actually resizes, but I was tricked by the XML that comes and make an area to the View on a aspect ratio that the Video won't support. Also, I already tried to add the MediaController by this way, but it's shown over the Activity.

Answer (score 16):

You can only change the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoViewRelative"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's well explained in http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html

Comment: This worked for me. I need to add android:layout_gravity="center"

Answer (score 2):

After you change your `LayoutParams` I think you will need to call `setLayoutParams` so the layout can be updated with the new params. After the call to `setLayoutParams` you may have to call the method `reqestLayout` to invalidate the layout and trigger a redraw of the view.

You will need to create a new instance of the `MediaController` and use the method `setMediaController` on the `VideoView` object.