# VideoView does not play mp4 videos

Tags: android, video

I  have an mp4 video thats 1200*780 resolution that I am not able to play on my android device.I am using android 2.1 device for testing the application.I am using video view to play videos on my emulator.But I had read somewhere that video view has a limitation that it will not play videos above 320px.What should I do if I want large videos to be played on my android device?

Answer (score 0):

You should resize video. For this you have create a custom class to VideoView and override onMeasure method. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031598/resize-video-to-fit-the-videoview) will help you. Its in detail.

Comment: thanks for the link..but that link explains to change the orientation.what I want to change the video resolution.Is there any other way to view the videos other than using video view?