# Android Video no start again

Tags: android, video, orientation, android-videoview

I want that when I turn the phone and change the screen orientation, the video continue playing where it was playing and no start again. I have tried change the Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and change in my activity

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        InitializeUI();
    }
```

does not work and start the video again when I change the orientation. Can anyone help me, please?

---

Thank you very much for the help, but I think that I have not explained well, my English is not very good. 
In the application I'm developing, I have a video that plays automatically when I turn the phone, the video starts again. I need, continues the video where he was playing. This problem is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video). I have tried to modify the code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video), but I have not worked. I've also been looking at the links you gave me you, but neither works. Is there a method, changing classes to solve the problem?. Thank you very much.

Comment: your InitializeUI() method is probably starting the video. You'd have to not call this from onConfigureChanged to get it to keep playing instead of restarting.

Comment: I tried to change and is still happening. I leave my new code. thanks.[code]@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  myvideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
  final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
  String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
  myvideo.setVideoPath(uri);
  myvideo.requestFocus();
  myvideo.start();
  myvideo.setMediaController(mediaController);
  mediaController.setAnchorView(myvideo);
  mediaController.show();

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the next code:

```
private int timevideo;
//Oncreate()
    Bundle returnData = (Bundle) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (returnData == null) {
            String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.videoname;
            myvideo.setVideoPath(uri);
            myvideo.requestFocus();
            myvideo.start();
        } else {
            String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.videoname;
            myvideo.setVideoPath(uri);
            timevideo = returnData.getInt("POSVIDEO");
            myvideo.seekTo(timevideo);
            myvideo.requestFocus();
            myvideo.start();
        }
@Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        timevideo = myvideo.getCurrentPosition();
        data.putInt("POSVIDEO", timevideo);
        return data;
    }
```

Thank you