# VideoView playback on orientation change problen

Tags: android, android-videoview, onconfigurationchanged

I have `VideoView` (with streaming online video) and I wanted it to continue playing while changing orientation, so I looked around at SO and found that you need to handle orientation change yourself, well ok, I added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to manifest, and everything worked as intended. But. Only if you dont have different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations.

So how do I handle `VideoView` in this case? I dont see a way to preserve it, because I have to set new layout in `onConfigurationChanged()`. Or maybe there is another way? I thought about retaining position at video, and then `seekTo()`, but how do I avoid rebuffering in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4434027/403455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, they only way I found is to actually remake existing layout on configuration change, using LayoutParameters. Not really a good idea, to be honest.