# Android Video not fitting the width in portrait of the videoview and not occupying full screen in landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen, android-videoview, portrait

Android video not fitting the width of the videoview when in portrait, how can i make the width of my video fit the width of my videoview when in portrait, and when i change orientation of the screen to landscape i would like the video to fill the whole screen like the youtube app does. when in portrait the video is to start from the top to the middle of the screen and  and when in landscape to fill the whole screen. here is what i have tried, i have also add links of the complete [screenshot](http://videoshare.loveworldapis.com/Screenshot.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="100" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="53" >
</VideoView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/low_tab"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/low"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/low" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/high_tab"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/high"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/high" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/audio_tab"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/audio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/audio" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/full_screen"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/full"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/full" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fresh"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/refresh" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:background="@drawable/comment_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liveblog_tab"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/live_blog" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addcom_tab"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/add_comment" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="33" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liveblog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/browser"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to have two different layouts. One for the portrait and the one for the landscape.
Create two xml files with the same name and put them into folders "layout-land" for landscape and "layout-port" for portrait.

And [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)  you can take a look how to handle orientation changes.

This can be the layout to make video view full screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT : This is How you can handle it in the method.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  // Checks the orientation of the screen
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(Your Landscape layout);
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(Your portrait layout);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have this in my manifest android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden", which prevents my layout-land from been recognized. If i decide to remove it, from the manifest, can i only just use the above code you provide in the layout-land

Comment: If you have this in manifest then you need to handle the configuration changes yourself. in this case onConfigurationChanged() method is called by your Activity. Here you can set your new content view and handle the data you already have in your Activity. e.g. You can resume your video here.

Comment: Downvote has been given recently. Please explain the reason for downvote rather than just downvoting and leaving. If you think there is something wrong with the given answer, you should share your thoughts with people who think the answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

For **linearlayout** I'm not sure. But using **relativelayout** you can do this as below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</VideoView>

//your other xml content 
....
....
....

</RelativeLayout>
```

And If you want the **videoview** to be filled in height too. then you need to do this code:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</VideoView>

//your other xml content 
....
....
....

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if it's helped. Thanks.

Comment: @blessed 3 years later we are still waiting.

Comment: it's 5 years now

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void fitStretchClick() {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(arrayListVideos.get(mPosition).getSongPath()));
    Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();

    float width = ((float) bmp.getWidth()) / ((float) bmp.getHeight());
    int width2 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float f = (float) width2;
    float f2 = (float) height;
    float f3 = f / f2;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mVideoView.getLayoutParams();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = mVideoView.getLayoutParams();
    if (changedNow) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mVideoView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        mVideoView.setLayoutParams(params);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stretch To Screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        changedNow = false;
        return;
    } else {
        changedNow = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fit To Screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (width > f3) {
            layoutParams.width = width2;
            layoutParams.height = (int) (f / width);
            mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            return;
        }
        layoutParams.width = (int) (width * f2);
        layoutParams.height = height;
        mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

}
```