# in android how to load video current position?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I've got a simple videoview that plays a video. I'm trying to get it to play smoothly and not rebuffer or restart the Activity upon orientation change from portrait to landscape. Here's the video code:

```
        uriStr = ("http://video.com/video/" + yyyyMdd_Str + "/" + yyyyMdd_Str + ".mp4");

    testMediaCon1_MC = new MediaController(this);
    testMediaCon1_MC.setAnchorView(testVideo1_VV);
    testVideo1_VV.setMediaController(testMediaCon1_MC);
    testVideo1_VV.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    testVideo1_VV.setVideoPath(uriStr);
    testVideo1_VV.requestFocus();
    testVideo1_VV.start();
```

And I think to make the video play smoothly on orientation change I have to get the video's current position, then load that current position when the orientation change happens. So I have the code to get the video position:

```
    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
 if (testVideo1_VV.isPlaying()) out.putInt("pos", testVideo1_VV.getCurrentPosition());
}
```

But now I can't figure out what the code would be to load the video position here:

```
    @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle in) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(in);
 //load video position here
}
```

Any ideas? Or am I doing this totally wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `testVideo1_VV.seekTo`?

Comment: how would I code that if I'm starting with "if (testVideo1_VV.isPlaying()) out.putInt("pos", testVideo1_VV.getCurrentPosition());" ? testVideo1_VV.seekTo("pos"); isn't it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I figured out is that making the video full screen on orientation change isn't done in overriding `onRestoreInstanceState` like I thought, but in overriding  `onConfigurationChanged`. In the manifest, `android:configChanges="orientation"` should be called, then override `onConfigurationChanged` and here's how I got it to work for me:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        buttonsLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bufferLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoSA_VV
                .getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 1);
        videoSA_VV.setLayoutParams(lp);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        buttonsLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bufferLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoSA_VV
                .getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        videoSA_VV.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

}
```

The key is to set the visibility on the views that you don't want to display to GONE, then set them back to VISIBLE when the orientation changes back. And after setting the views to GONE, you stretch the VideoView to fill the parent view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seekTo` to restart playback from the saved position, but it doesn't solve the problem with rebuffering - once your VideoView is destroyed, buffers are flushed and before you can restart playback, media must be prepared and buffered again.

If you want to continue playback seamlessly after orientation change, you have to keep activity alive and handle the change yourself - see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: thanks msh, you're right, if I handle the change myself, the video plays seamlessly. But upon orientation change to landscape, the Activity is still using the portrait layout. How do I force the Activity to use the landscape layout in onConfigurationChanged()? What would the code look like?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video