# Stop Video View from AutoResizing Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, android-xml

I have implemented a video view within a relative layout. I have set specific `layoutWidth` and `layoutHeight` for my relative layout and am trying to match parent for the video view.

My problem is the video view wont respond to the code.

This is my XML view:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header -->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/video_menu_header" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why the videoView does not fill the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Resize VideoView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video/4452597#4452597)

Comment: The question is not clearly stated. "Won't respond to the code" is not really helpful. State what its doing, and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. What I was trying to do is resize the videoView according to the relativeLayout width and height. I modified the code to :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header -->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/video_menu_header" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```