# Full HD video in VideoView issues

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-videoview

I'm playing a Full HD video inside a VideoView, but my screen size is just 1216px x 684px.

The VideoView is cropping the video, but I want it scaled down. I found one "bug" that makes what I want, but surely it's not the best way. If I set 1px margin around the VideoView, it scales correctly.

The VideoView is inside a RelativeLayout, I tried to set centerInParent, "alignParentLeft, Right, Top and Bottom" but none of this works.

Is there another way to make VideoView correctly scale the source?

Another issue:
When I pause my VideoView, it goes dark, instead of freezing the image. Is there a way I could achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance for every reply.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4452597/3098658)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android VideoView orientation change with buffered video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Jay, actually I read this before, but I don't have the video size. As it is 1080P in this test I'm doing, it might be 720P or less. Do you know if there is a way to get video specs before playing it?