# How to stop re-loading of buffered video during orientation changes in android device

Tags: android

I have a `VideoView`  in which I want to play video after buffering complete.

I have managed two different xml code layouts for landscape and portrait each.

My issue is that when I change orientation of device, the video buffering restart again.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

android:configChanges="screenOrientation" in the activity tag of your Manifest file.

This way the activity will not be recreated.

I think this will help you.

Comment: actually a lot more has to be done not just the above

Answer (score 0):

actually you have to do a couple of things firstly handle the orientation yourself to do this you have to add this under the activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

now override onConfigurationChanged inside your activity.java file
```

After this it depends on your layout if there is anything under the videoview then hide it and change the layout params of the videoview like this,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     //your logic for landscape
    } else {
            //your logic for potrait
    }
}
```

Ps:things might not go very smoothly during orientation change in videoview, refer this answer also it might be helpful
[Android VideoView orientation change with buffered video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video)