# Android VideoView resizing won't resize video

Tags: android, android-videoview, layoutparams

I have a `VideoView` which resizes on keyboard events. I observed that the video (played by VideoView) will not resize even though the VideoView's layout is changed (the changes are clearly visible). Is there any call I need to make to resize the video to the new layout?

I have tried 'invalidate()' and 'requestLayout()', but they did not work.

Comment: When the layout change? change while playing or  change layout first, then play viedeo

Comment: Change while playing

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a custom VideoView since it require to invoke these 2 methods :

`onMeasure()`  and  `onConfigurationChanged()`

this Answer has explained in very deep detail, please check below:

[Android VideoView orientation change with buffered video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to re-actualize my VideoView size by doing this after changing it's owner Layout:

```
mVideoView.getHolder().setSizeFromLayout();
```

Comment: This Worked for me. First i called invalidate() on the most parent ViewGroup that contained the VideoView and then called getHolder().setSizeFromLayout() on the VideoView

Answer (score -1):

Use FrameLayout as parent of videoView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <VideoView
       android:id="@+id/myVideo"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```