# Scaling image on top of VideoView gets cropped

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, android-videoview

I am trying my hands at Android App Development and facing some issues related to VideoView.
I am using animator to scale my image. Code is as below:

> MainActivity.java

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
private SurfaceView vidSurface;
private VideoView videoView;
String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    try {
        Uri videoURL = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoURL);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.image_anim);
    set.setTarget(imageView);
    set.start();
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@raw/logo"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> image_anim.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:startOffset="5000"
        android:valueTo="2"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:startOffset="5000"
        android:valueTo="2"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

The image displays fine when activity is started. But as and when it scales, I cannot see the image beyond its original dimensions. In other words, it gets cropped on beyond the area of the original dimensions.

I believe it is somewhat related to the following issue with VideoView but have no idea how to resolve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22101290/3530685

For better understanding, this is what is happening
[image: Before Scaling]

[image: After Scaling]

Scaling happens fine if I remove VideoView. How can I do properly scale image without the image getting cropped due to VideoView?

Edit: I tested it on another device with Android 5.1.1 and it works fine. But does not work fine in emulator or device with Android 4.0.4

Comment: `"I am using animator to scale my image"` animator as its name says is used for animating something, if you want to scale your `ImageView` use scale type = "matrix"

Comment: @pskink I want to add a couple of more images and some texts to create an animation set on top of the VideoView. Any reason why animator shouldn't be used?